# Java Key Range with a map or some structure

Tags: java, types, hashmap

I need a map, and in the map I need a range  with a key:

For example

```
Map<Range,Value> name;
```

where Range can be

for example values between `0 - 600`, the other range can be `601 - 900, ...`

And for example if I need `name.containsKey(480)` I need true because is in the first range, And If I need the value `name.get(780)` I need the value in the range `601-900`

I don't know what is the best dataType to do it.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Are there any gaps between ranges? If not, you can use a `TreeMap`. Otherwise, consider Guava's [`RangeMap`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/RangeMap.html).

Comment: Can ranges overlap?

Comment: `contains` relies on the relationship of the `hashCode` of the objects, so I doubt theres' a "simple" solution based on the current implementation

Comment: @MadProgrammer *`contains` relies on the relationship of the `hashCode` of the objects* - if hash tables are based on hash codes, this does not mean everything else must be based on hash code as well. Nothing obliges `Map` implementations to use hash codes.

Comment: @lexicore Sorry, took the meaning to literally

Comment: Not The Ranges are not overlapping